# gin index 'tid' array does not match table array

Tags: postgresql

I created the following table and inserted some values into it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE query_all_lexeme (
        payload text,
        normalized tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', payload)) STORED
    );
    
INSERT INTO query_all_lexeme (payload)
    VALUES ('fat cats ate rats');

INSERT INTO query_all_lexeme (payload)
    VALUES ('summarize the functions and operators that are provided for full text searching');

INSERT INTO query_all_lexeme (payload)
    VALUES ('Constructs a phrase query');

INSERT INTO query_all_lexeme (payload)
SELECT
    'Constructs a phrase query this is a test'
FROM
    generate_series(1, 10000);

INSERT INTO query_all_lexeme (payload)
SELECT
    'Constructs a phrase query this is a test'
FROM
    generate_series(1, 100);
```

Then I created a gin index:

```
CREATE INDEX query_all_lexeme_vector ON query_all_lexeme USING gin (normalized);
```

And then I run the query below to get gin index info:

```
SELECT * FROM
        gin_metapage_info (get_raw_page ('query_all_lexeme_vector', 0)) \gx
```

Result:

```
+-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------+
| pending_head     | 4294967295 |
| pending_tail     | 4294967295 |
| tail_free_size   | 0          |
| n_pending_pages  | 0          |
| n_pending_tuples | 0          |
| n_total_pages    | 14         |
| n_entry_pages    | 1          |
| n_data_pages     | 12         |
| n_entries        | 15         |
| version          | 2          |
+------------------+------------+
```

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            flags,
            p
        FROM
            generate_series(1, 13) AS p,
            gin_page_opaque_info (get_raw_page ('query_all_lexeme_vector', p)))
    SELECT
        array_agg(p)
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        flags::text = '{data,leaf,compressed}';
```

return

```
+----------------------+
|      array_agg       |
+----------------------+
| {3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13} |
+----------------------+
```

In the following query, I should expect at least one row for the column **`gin_tid_vs_table_tid`** value that is true. However, the column values are all false.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        (unnest(normalized)).lexeme AS elements
        , array_agg(ctid) AS ctids
    FROM
        query_all_lexeme
    GROUP BY
        1
)
SELECT
    elements
    , pg_typeof(ctids)
    , ctids = (
        SELECT
            tids
        FROM
            gin_leafpage_items (get_raw_page ('query_all_lexeme_vector' , 3))
        ORDER BY
            1
        LIMIT 1) AS gin_tid_vs_table_tid
FROM
    cte;
```

I have already run vacuum analyze. Now the data is very stable (only `SELECT`), and the `tid` value is stabilized. So why the last query's column `gin_tid_vs_table_tid` has false values?
My logic is like `gin` index stored `lexemes` and `lexemes`' corresponding `tid` (physical tuple location). So the `gin` index `tid` should be equal as `array_agg(ctid)` with the same `lexeme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic would only apply if one index entry were guaranteed to contain *all* the ctids for a given lexeme.  There is no such guarantee, and can't be because index tuples have a strictly bounded size which is far less than enough to contain all possible ctids.

Maybe you could switch from array equality to overlaps or contains (`&&`, `@>`).

Comment: but the flags  is compressed?  also  in the menu: A GIN index stores a set of (key, posting list) pairs, where a posting list is a set of row IDs in which the key occurs. The same row ID can appear in multiple posting lists, since an item can contain more than one key. Each key value is stored only once, so a GIN index is very compact for cases where the same key appears many times.